# Exec vs ExecWait vs ExecShell vs nsExec::Exec vs nsExec::ExecToLog vs nsExec::ExecToStack vs ExecDos vs ExeCmd

Tags: nsis, shellexecute

Can I know what are the differences between each `Exec`, `ExecWait`, `ExecShell`, `nsExec::Exec`, `nsExec::ExecToLog,` `nsExec::ExecToStack`, `ExecDos` and `ExecCmd`, as in when to use which?

I 've posted the various execute calls I know. I am trying to make a comprehensive list, so that it helps future visitors..

1. `Exec`: Plainly execute the called string, be it some application, console or file.
2. `ExecWait`: Executes like `Exec` but waits till the process exits.
3. `ExecShell`: **What is it for?**
4. `nsExec::Exec`: Just like `Exec` or `ExecWait` but only for command prompt and that too without opening the console window. I am unsure if it waits for process to exit. **Does `nsExec::Exec` wait for child process to exit?**
5. `nsExec::ExecToLog`: `The documentation says ExecToLog` is similar to plain `nsExec` but it outputs to log window. **What does that mean, what is a log window?**
6. `nsExec::ExecToStack`: The documentation says `ExecToStack` is similar to plain `nsExec` but it pushes output to stack. I get that.
7. `ExecDos`: Same as `nsExec::ExecToStack` but it additionally (**Is it not**?)

   a. takes string parameter that serves as stdin for running application.

   b. works in both sync/async mode.

   c. it works out of section - for .onInit check outs.
8. `ExecCmd`: Same as `ExecDos` but it doesn't require these

   ```
   ExpandEnvStrings $3 %COMSPEC% 
   ExecDos::exec  /C
   ```

   parts. **Am I correct?**

Comment: You may include [Timeout::ExecTimeout](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecTimeout_plug-in) too, for those who need to kill child process if it takes too long to complete.

Comment: @FranciscoR Feel free to edit the question and add it (along with its purpose). I'm not so knowledgeable about the one you mentioned.

Comment: Realistically, the explanations for what each command should do belong in an answer, _not_ in the question itself.  "Am I correct?" = bad StackOverflow question.  I'm tempted to move those bits to an answer, but there's already an answer that moving would invalidate.

Comment: @MooingDuck the problem is if I ask a question like that it might very well get closed since the question would look too broad and loaded and without research effort. I wanted to show some effort put by myself, at the same time quite complete with explanation for all the execute commands in one place. Of course someone can put them all as one answer, that will be good too.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**1) 2) 3)**

`Exec` and `ExecWait` use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) internally and can only start programs and batch files.

`ExecShell` uses [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which means that it can also launch any registered filetype (.txt .chm etc) and URLs. It should also be used if the program you are starting needs to elevate with UAC.

**4)**

nsExec redirects stdout so a console window is not visible when the child process executes. And yes, it waits.

**5)**

The log window on the instfiles page.

**7)**

Yes, both ExecDos and ExecCmd are more advanced versions of nsExec.

**8)**

Correct

Answer (score 4):

`ExecWait` waits and thus can **return** stuff! [docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#execwait).

`ExecShell` is also able to **hide the output window**. [docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#execshell)

`ExecCmd` is considered outdated and superseded by `ExecDos`. both are extra plugins for NSIS that are not shipped by default. [docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in)

Comment: You say ExecShell is able to hide the output window. I've been trying to run a batch file without opening a command window but I can't do it. Neither SW_HIDE nor SW_MINIMIZE seem to have any effect.

Comment: Whow.. Sorry. It's been a while since I dealt with this. I suppose calling a batch file will ALWAYS show a command window. No matter how you call it. That's what a batch file does: run stuff in a command window.

Comment: I've discovered you can run a silent batch file using nsExec::Exec