# is there a way to run nsis code as user with regular privileges and a third party exe (within) as an administrator

Tags: installation, admin, nsis, winamp

Is there a way to run "nsis" code as user with regular privileges and a third party exe (within) as an administrator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to launch an exe with administrator privileges from within your installer, you need to use [Execshell](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.3). See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708779/exec-vs-execwait-vs-execshell-vs-nsexecexec-vs-nsexecexectolog-vs-nsexecex) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Francisco. This solution does not work for a "Guest" machine. it asks for admin privilege.

Comment: What you ask for (if I understand correctly) is how to bypass the UAC control which is exactly designed for this purpose.