# Run Powershell Silently via NSIS

Tags: powershell, nsis, silent-installer

I have a powershell script that I want to run silently.
I am using NSIS script, it's still promoting the powershell command prompt when .exe file is ran..

Is there a way so it will silently.

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include x64.nsh


OutFile "script.exe"
SilentInstall silent
RequestExecutionLevel admin

Function .onInit
    SetSilent silent
FunctionEnd

Section
    SetOutPath $EXEDIR
    File "script.ps1"
    IfSilent 0 +2
        ExecWait "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\script.ps1 -FFFeatureOff"
SectionEnd

Function .onInstSuccess
    Delete "script.ps1"
FunctionEnd
```

There is an example here that uses silent install, but I couldn't get it working when I tried it. `http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/silent.nsi`

Comment: Why are you using IfSilent, "SilentInstall silent" will force it to always be silent.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ExecWait "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File .\script.ps1 -FFFeatureOff"
```

More info: [PowerShell.exe Command-Line Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)

Comment: This will briefly display a console window on the screen because the console window is created before the powershell process is able to hide it.

Comment: @Anders Yep, my bad, I should have checked this myself. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 4):

Powershell.exe is a console application and console applications get a console window by default and the NSIS silent parameter has no impact on console windows created for child processes. A parameter like `-WindowStyle Hidden` that can be passed to the child process will always cause a console window to be visible on the screen for a short period of time because Windows will create the console window before the child process starts running.

If you need to hide a console window then you should use a plugin. [nsExec](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt) is part of the default install or you could use a 3rd-party plugin like [ExecDos](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in) that offers more advanced features like stdin handling.

If you don't need to wait for the child process then you can try `ExecShell` as suggested by [Serge Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33123136/3501)...

Answer (score 3):

You can try ExecShell for this, it allows to hide console via SW_HIDE flag:

```
ExpandEnvStrings $0 "%COMSPEC%"
ExecShell "" '"$0"' "/C powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\script.ps1 -FFFeatureOff" SW_HIDE
```

Also, refer to this question:
[Exec vs ExecWait vs ExecShell vs nsExec::Exec vs nsExec::ExecToLog vs nsExec::ExecToStack vs ExecDos vs ExeCmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708779/exec-vs-execwait-vs-execshell-vs-nsexecexec-vs-nsexecexectolog-vs-nsexecex)